# Method that acts like a static method AND a regular method

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I was wondering if there is a way for a class to define a method that behaves like a static method (can be called without an instance variable) and a regular method (can be called with an instance variable).

Im making an RSA module that would help me solve RSA problems, the initialization goes like this:

```py
class RSA:

    def __init__(self, n: int, e: int, c: int, p=None, q=None, phi=None):
        self.n = n
        self.e = e
        self.c = c
        self.p = p
        self.q = q

        assert p == None or gmpy2.is_prime(p), 'p must be prime'
        assert q == None or gmpy2.is_prime(q), 'q must be prime'

        self.phi = phi
```

and in that class, there is a method that would factorize n into p and q which goes like this (the algorithm used is irrelevant so I wont bother explaining):

```py
    def fermat_factorization(self, n=None):
        if n == None:
            n = self.n

        t_ = gmpy2.isqrt(n)+1 
        counter = 0 
        t = t_ + counter
        temp = gmpy2.isqrt((t * t) - n)
        
        while((temp * temp) != ((t * t) - n)):
            counter += 1 
            t = t_ + counter
            temp = gmpy2.isqrt((t * t) - n)
        
        s = temp
        p = t + s
        q = t - s
        return p, q
```

that implementation does not work. What I wanted to do is for that method to be dynamic, i.e. can be called externally by simply

```py
p, q = RSA.fermat_factorization(n) # n is some large number
```

yet can also be called on an instance like:

```py
s1 = RSA(n, 65537, c) # c and n is some large number
p, q = s1.fermat_factorization() # without specifying n because it is already an instance attribute
```

Comment: I've seen some "messy" solutions (defining the function twice then reassigning the function in the initialization) but none of them seemed pretty so I decided to post this question

Comment: Have a regular method that passes any required instance variables to the static method as parameters, and returns the result?

Comment: Having two functions with similar names and basically does the same thing somewhat bothers me, sorry for being nitpicky...

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: well sometimes I just want to see how n factorizes before creating an instance variable, for example n can have 4 factors, p1, p2, q1, q2 with p1 and p2 being consecutive primes and q1 and q2 also being consecutive primes, since fermat factorization returns two numbers that are close to each other, it would return p1*q2 and p2*q1 but that is far from an answer so creating an instance would be undesirable

Comment: Basically: have a variadic function (`*args`) and test whether you receive one or two args, and decide from there which is which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, you use modules for that kind of stuff, not classes:

in `rsa.py`

```
def fermat_factorization(n):
   """Ordinary function"""

class RSA:
    def fermat_factorization(self):
        """Method"""
        return fermat_factorization(self.n)
```

somewhere else:

```
 import rsa

 x = rsa.fermat_factorization(100)

 obj = rsa.RSA(...)
 y = obj.fermat_factorization()
```

Having a single function that behaves some way or another depending on how it's called is a recipe for disaster. Don't do that.